# kendo Scheduler Set MinorTickCount(0) is disale times but create bug when click all day date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to disable the time part in Scheduler. 
when I make .MinorTickCount(0) is hiding all the times but click event on all day date slots doesn't work fine.

when I remove the .MinorTickCount(0) then click event works fine. but I want to remove all the times. I need only all day only.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<FEWO.Web.Models.MeetingViewModel>()
.Name("scheduler")
.Date(new DateTime(2007, 12, 13))
.Selectable(true)
.AllDaySlot(true)
.MinorTickCount(0)
```

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the desired behavior is not supported out of the box and custom solution would be needed.  For example you can try hiding the second table using the DataBound event as demonstrated in [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/Usej/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using binding the vertical grouping then the above way makes you some issues..it will resources also. then the only approach is using style hiding using jquery

1. Make kendo properties like below,

   .Selectable(false).AllDaySlot(true)

   .MajorTick(1440)
   .MinorTickCount(1)

Now you will see two rows per resource and hide the time raw using jquery

```
$(function () {
    $(".k-middle-row").hide();
    $(".k-scheduler-times-all-day").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
        $(this).closest('th').prev('th').attr("rowspan", "1")
    });

});
```